# Return a report date in the Page Header for a Crystal Report that has no records

Tags: date, crystal-reports, report

I have a relatively basic Crystal Report that will most often return no records. As a result, the file date which I use for the report date in the page header of the report doesn't appear, and of course I need it to appear, Tried numerous methods and none work. The report is exported to Excel so any solution can't mess with the Excel rendering (data only) Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: How you are displaying file date and did you try to add it in report header?

Comment: file date is the effective date of the report and data. Simply putting that field in the page header leaves a blank or null value, and as I said, I need the report to show the file date when there is no data on the report.

Comment: The report is a basic table build - it isn't command based. All tables including the one having the file date are joined to the master table via a left outer join. And no join changes that I have tried made a difference.

Comment: Faisal, sorry if I didn't answer your question - yes, I tried putting it on the report header and that didn't work. The essence of the issue is that the report returns null values for all fields, but even so, I need the report to show file date (datetime formatted to mm/dd/yy) as well as the other column headers that do appear in the page header.